# I'm creating a reusable alert box in Angular 9. When I'm changing the alert type, the proper class is not applied

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a reusable alert component in angular 9. But I'm getting an issue. In the alert-box selector when I'm trying to give the alert type, it's not at all changing the alert type.
Only I'm getting the plain text. Styles are also not being applied.
Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

Usage:

```
<app-alert-box alertType="warning">
        Hi this is alert
</app-alert-box>
```

My Code:

alert-box.component.html

```
    <ng-container>
        <div
            [ngClass]="{
                'alert-danger': alertType == 'danger',
                'alert-info': alertType == 'info',
                'alert-success': alertType == 'success',
                'alert-warning': alertType == 'warning'
            }"
            class="alert"
            role="alert"
        >

            <span class="alert-content" #alertContent>

                <ng-content></ng-content>

            </span>
            <button (click)="alertClose()" *ngIf="closeButton" aria-label="Close">
X
            </button>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

alert-box.component.scss

```
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

  .danger {
    background-color: #f44336;
  }
  .success {
    background-color: #4caf50;
  }
  .info {
    background-color: #2196f3;
  }
  .warning {
    background-color: #ff9800;
  }
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

alert-box.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-alert-box",
  templateUrl: "./alert-box.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./alert-box.component.scss"]
})
export class AlertBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() alertType = "info";
  @Input() closeButton = false;
  @Input() autoClose = false;
  @Input() autoCloseAfter = 5000;

  alertOpen = true;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.autoClose) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.alertClose();
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }, this.autoCloseAfter);
    }
  }

  alertClose(): void {
    this.alertOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you produce stackblitz ?

Comment: okk i will produce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You classes are called `alert-danger`, `alert-success`,... but your css is just referring to `alert`, `success`
Change to css to

```
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

  &.alert-danger {
    background-color: #f44336;
  }
  &.alert-success {
    background-color: #4caf50;
  }
 &.alert-info {
    background-color: #2196f3;
  }
  &.alert-warning {
    background-color: #ff9800;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovdk7m)